# Searching for a variable number of terms in a MySQL database using Laravel Fluent

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, fluent, eloquent

I have the following MySQL table:

```
cases
  id            INT
  diagnosis     TEXT
  description   TEXT
```

This is represented in Laravel by a `LibraryCase` model.

When a user enters a search term I get matching cases using the following:

```
// $user_query is the (escaped and purified) user input
$matches = LibraryCase::where('diagnosis', 'LIKE', $user_query)
                      ->or_where('description', LIKE, $user_query)
                      ->paginate(10);
```

Say I have a case and the description is 'sonic the hedgehog'. If the user enters 'sonic' or 'hedgehog' it returns the case. If the user enters 'sonic hedgehog', nothing is returned. This makes sense but I can't figure out how to split `$user_query` up into individual words and then add each of these to my query to LibraryCase?

Am I making a mountain out of a molehill? It seems like this is something that is done alot...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
$matches = LibraryCase::where('id','>',0);

$user_query = "sonic hedgehog";

foreach(explode(' ', $user_query) as $word)
{
    $matches = $matches->or_where('diagnosis', 'LIKE', $word);
    $matches = $matches->or_where('description', 'LIKE', $word);
}

return $matches->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Afraid not :(. I get a `Call to a member function or_where() on a non-object` error on $matches

Comment: Sorry, paginate is like a get(), just edited with something that might work. You need a Query Builder object in that first line and there might be a better way to get one empty than filtering all ids, but this should work.